# Task environment is not working

Tags: errors, tasks

I am using a task environment but it is not working. My sample code is

```
\begin{tasks}[label=(\arabic*)]
\task 1
\task 2
\task 1
\task 3
\task 4
\end{tasks}
```

But if I use the same code without `[label=(\arabic*)]` then it is working.
Please do help.

Comment: `\usepackage{tasks}`? This works without problems: http://dpaste.com/3YHZ7NP (expires in 10 days)

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I have used tasks package. But it is not working when I use [label=(\arabic*)] or any other label.

Comment: Is your distribution up-to-date? Which is your error? I got an error if I try @HenriMenke's code on Overleaf (which is not up-to-date but uses TeXLive 2018).

Comment: Which version of tasks do you have? The syntax for labels has changed since version 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bernard said in his comment, the syntax for labels has changed since version 1.0 of package `tasks`.

If you have a version older than 1.0 but at least 0.9 or newer, for example, if you're using Overleaf, which has

```
tasks.sty    2016/08/13 v0.12 Horizontalcolumnedlists (CN),
```

you should use `counter-format={<counter specs>}`.

This option is now deprecated, it set a custom label in a peculiar way. The letters `tsk` are replaced with the task-counter. An optional argument directly following these letters specifies the counter format: `1`: `\arabic`, `a`: `\alph`, `A`: `\Alph`, `r`:
`\roman` and `R`: `\Roman`.

You can find the old [documentation of the package](https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/blob/1a3ee131b838c84efa8a2e9bd4d059c64a75a782/tasks_en.pdf) in its repository on GitHub.

This works on Overleaf, I hope it works also for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[1]), label-width=4em]
\task 1
\task 2
\task 1
\task 3
\task 4
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]